# Movie where the father sees (and kills) zombies, but it turns out that they were imagined

Tags: story-identification, movie, zombie

The scene I remember extends a dad seeing zombies everywhere and desperately trying to get to his family and bring them to safety. Upon arriving there the movie watcher realizes that there are no zombies and all the people the father killed are his neighbours and friends. His terrified family, being shocked, agrees to come with him and they 'flee' by car.

I know it wasn't an AAA production and also not a budget or trash movie but somewhere in between.

Comment: i saw a sort of animated (more like showing pages of a graphic novel) that was a prequel to I am Legend. People infected with the virus saw humans as monsters. a girl is appealing to her father to let her inside a shelter. this was set in India. Not sure if this is close enough to what u are asking about.

Comment: not really, but sounds interesting

Comment: [Frailty](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frailty_(2001_film)) with Bill Paxton and Matthew McConnauhey has some similarities.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the community! Just wanted to double check -- what language was this movie broadcasted in? English?

Comment: There was also a new (Outer Limits or Twilight Zone)? episode where solders wearing special suits were gassed by there superiors to see the enemies as monsters, so they kill them on sight. when in actuality they were civilians(?) in a facility their superiors wanted to capture or destroy.

Comment: The TV episode in the comment above sounds like "Men Against Fire" from "Black Mirror".

Comment: I don't think it was this particular one (I think the protagonist was a young woman) but adding to the list for future 'similar story identification'... I remember there was some episode of an anthology series called "Fear Itself" (episode "New Years Day") with a zombie apocalypse but it was revealed that the protagonist was the zombie and most of the people she interacted with were normal.

Comment: @Sensoray I watched it in another language but I'm pretty sure the original language was English.

Comment: @djangoKunzmann what was the language? it might help us find it.